# Function not returning position object from googlemaps geocode

Tags: javascript, google-maps, position, geocode

I have a function that gets the latLng from an adress with googles geocode.

```
function geoCode(address){
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        var pos = {
            lat:results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
            lng:results[0].geometry.location.lng()
        };
        return pos;
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
}
```

When I console log the "pos" object in this function I get the positions, but when i try to console.log it in an other function for example the one below

```
function foo(){
    var pos = geoCode(place);
    console.log(pos.lat);
}
```

I get the following alert:
**TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'pos.lat')**

There seems something wrong with the return of the pos object.

Comment: The geocoder is asynchronous, you can't return anything from the callback function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like geocodezip said your `geoCode` function is asynchronous.  This means that when you call it from your `foo` function, `foo` finishes before it gets data back from `geoCode` which is what gives you your `undefined` error.  What you can do is wrap your `geoCode` function in a Promise and resolve the promise with the data from google.